# Wamp mysql root password reset - not working

Tags: mysql, passwords, wamp, root, reset

I need some assistance with my MySQL application (installed as part of the WAMP Server 3.0.0).
I suspect somewhere along the lines MySQL became corrupted.  When trying to log on with my root account, I get the following error:

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using
>   password: ES)

I then followed the steps to reset the root password as per many of the Stackoverflow and MySQL guides but without any luck.

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-windows-excerpt/5.7/en/resetting-permissions-windows.html
- [Resetting MySQL root password not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23025896/resetting-mysql-root-password-not-working)
- [reset/change mysql root password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28341788/reset-change-mysql-root-password)

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQJpc.png)

I suspect the only way forward is perhaps a reinstallation of MySQL, however, I only have the raw database files and not the most recent dump files.  (Current dump files about 2 weeks old).

What are my options?

- Is there something I overlooked?
- Shall I proceed with new installation?  If so, how do I restore the existing raw database files?

Appreciate any assistance.

Kind Regards

Comment: Check this out before throwing everything away https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29070501/regaining-access-to-lost-mysql-password-for-phpmyadmin-on-wamp/29073563#29073563

Comment: Thanks @RiggsFolly .  I will attempt this solution and let you know the outcome.

Comment: @RiggsFolly, You are the man.  Everything working perfectly again.  Thanks so much!